# Can I import a Kony Visualizer project directly into Kony Studio from a Visualization Cloud?

Tags: temenos-quantum

I was thinking this would be part of the cloud offering but I can't figure out how to do it.

Is the only way to import into Studio from Visualizer to use a local copy of the Visualizer project file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to be very good feature. But currently kony is not providing this feature.